# Relationship between power band in frequency band of oscillating light and that frequency

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

If one shines a light on an electrode, the electrode has a change in voltage due to the photoelectric effect. Thus, if one shines a light whose luminance oscillates sinuosidally with time, the voltage measured by the electrode oscillates with the same frequency. By recording this data, performing an FFT on the data, and taking the modulus squared, one finds the power bands for each frequency. I am interested in the relationship between the power band corresponding to the frequency at which the luminance of the light was oscillating and that frequency itself. I have obtained data with this method and found that the product of this power band and the frequency of light oscillation is roughly constant, but I do not understand why. I am not very versed in physics, so I hope this is a well-posed question with a simple answer, but let me know if more information is necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.